# walk vs map for processing a seq

Tags: clojure

As I understand walk and map both apply a function to a seq. (walk also allows the application of an `outer` function post processing). However what are the idiomatic cases of using one over the other ?

Comment: Applying a function to a seq is the job of `map`. Use `walk` when you have to traverse both through and recursively into the entire structure.

Comment: @A.Webb can you post it as an answer. I would like to mark it as the reply. also will appreciate if you can point to some examples of walk.

Comment: Does mine not answer your question?

Comment: @sethev Yes, I think yours does answer the question, so would be happy to see it accepted. I was going to edit yours to add another example, but got far too long winded, so I did end up submitting another answer anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Applying a function to a seq is the job of map. Use walk when you have to traverse both through and recursively into the entire structure.**

Some examples of `walk`s may be found at [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk), also available at the REPL, e.g. `(user/clojuredocs clojure.walk/postwalk)`. Many of the examples are pedagogic and could and should be done with `map` or `for` (and sometimes `reduce`) in practice.

The typical use case for a `walk` is when you have a nested structure that you wish to process recursively. Some examples where this might be useful are the `clojure.walk` namespace itself, e.g. look at `(source clojure.walk/keywordize-keys)`. [Note, if you want to process it iteratively or at will, use zippers (or `tree-seq` for some simpler iterative cases).]

Another example that comes to mind is interpreting parse trees:

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as w])

(def t [+ [* [- 6 2] [/ 9 3]] [* 2 [+ 7 8]]])

(w/postwalk #(if (and (coll? %) (fn? (first %))) (apply (first %) (next %)) %) t)
;=> 42
```

Perhaps useful if, e.g., replacing `fn?` with an `allowed-fn?`, etc. to evaluate an [edn](/questions/tagged/edn) expression, instead of invoking the too powerful eval compiler:

```
(eval t) ;=> [#<core$_PLUS_ ... ]
```

Oops, forms are lists, not vectors:

```
(def s (w/postwalk #(if (coll? %) (apply list %) %) t))
s ;=> (#<core$_PLUS_ ... )
(eval s) ;=> 42
```

Ah, notice here another use of a `walk` -- recursively changing the structure from nested vectors to nested lists.

An iterative example to meditate upon:

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as w])

(def s1 (range 8))
s1 ;=> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
(map inc s1)
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
(w/postwalk #(if (number? %) (inc %) %) s1)
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)

(def s2 (partition 2 s1))
s2 ;=> ((0 1) (2 3) (4 5) (6 7))
(map (partial map inc) s2)
;=> ((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (7 8))
(w/postwalk #(if (number? %) (inc %) %) s2)
;=> ((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (7 8))

(def s3 (partition 2 s2))
s3 ;=> ((0 1) (2 3) (4 5) (6 7))
(map (partial map (partial map inc)) s3)
;=> (((1 2) (3 4)) ((5 6) (7 8)))
(w/postwalk #(if (number? %) (inc %) %) s3)
;=> (((1 2) (3 4)) ((5 6) (7 8)))

(def s4 (partition 2 s3))
s4 ;=> ((((0 1) (2 3)) ((4 5) (6 7))))
(map (partial map (partial map (partial map inc))) s4)
;=> ((((1 2) (3 4)) ((5 6) (7 8))))
(w/postwalk #(if (number? %) (inc %) %) s4)
;=> ((((1 2) (3 4)) ((5 6) (7 8))))
```

Answer (score 10):

The semantics for `map` are basically: apply the function to each item in the collection and return the results lazily in a sequence:

```
(map inc #{0 1 2}) ;outputs (when realized) (1 2 3)
```

Note that the input was a set but the output is a sequence.

The semantics for walk are basically: make a collection of the same type where each item has been replaced by the value of the `inner` function for that item, return the result of applying `outer` to the new collection:

```
(walk inc identity #{0 1 2}) ;outputs #{1 2 3}
```

If you look at the source code for the other functions in the walk API (http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html), you can see how the to make walks recursive as well (or just use those other functions).

As far as idioms go, I'm not sure. But `walk` is more complex so you probably should stick to `map` in cases where you don't need the semantics that `walk` offers.

Comment: I think the other answer better illustrates the difference. However +1 for your effort and appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

For `map`, I think the idiomatic use case is quite clear: when you need to transform everything in a sequence, use it.

For `clojure.walk/walk`, I think the idiomatic use case is: when you need to transform everything in a sequence and then do an `apply fn` operation.

```
(clojure.walk/walk second #(apply +  %)  [["a" 1] ["b" 2] ["c" 3]])
;; => 6

(clojure.walk/walk first #(apply concat %)  [["ab" 1] ["b" 2] ["c" 3]])
;; => (\a \b \b \c)

(mapcat first [["ab" 1] ["b" 2] ["c" 3]])
;; => (\a \b \b \c)
```

Note the similarity between `clojure.walk/walk` and `mapcat`, I personally consider walk is the general form of mapcat.